# IntelliJ: included .jar's property file cannot be found by the included .jar

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ 12.1.2 and am having a problem including a .jar with a property file into my project.

I have a folder of third party stuff; its structure is like this:

```
UAT
 +-MainLibrary.jar
 +-ini
 |  +-properties.ini
 +-lib
    +-lib1.jar
    +-lib2.jar
    +-lib3.jar
```

In IntelliJ I have included the UAT folder as a dependency (File > Project Structure > Modules in left nav > Dependencies tab) and in my Java program I have put `import MainLibrary;` and I am able to create objects of type MainLibrary so that part is working.  What is not working is MainLibrary cannot find its `properties.ini` file and I don't know how to tell IntelliJ where to locate it.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a library for `UAT` directory and there are jar files, IDEA will configure it as `jar directories` type of the library: only `*.jar` files present in this folder will be added to the classpath, `ini` folder will not be added, jar files under `lib` folder will not be added.

The solution is to add additional paths to the library: `ini` and `lib`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation of the problem.  I do not know how to add additional paths to `ini` and `lib`.  If you have time to explain the steps I need to take to do that, I would appreciate it.

Comment: In the library configuration press the **+** button and select **Attach files or Directories...**. [Here is the screenshot](http://img827.imageshack.us/img827/6813/20130504014338.png). More details [available in help](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html).